# Multiple input type 'file' fields getting empty after form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I'm making a form to upload photos and I'm having multiple no. of input type 'file' fields with different field names under a single form.

Also, I'm using ajax to to send those files. I'm new to coding PHP, and I've put around 6 hours to it while searching for solutions and treid lots of variations in it but couldn't solve.

The problem I'm facing is that only one field's file is passing to PHP and other fields are empty. Getting only one fields's output after file moving successfully. After checking with 'print_r' I found those array empty.

My images files are under 250 KB and JPG. So is there not any file size and type issue.

HTML Code (echo from PHP after AJAX request):

```
<form action=\"upload.php\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" class=\"upload-inputs\">

    <div class=\"upload-wrap\">
        <input placeholder=\"Choose a file..\" class=\"file-name\" type=\"text\">
        <input type=\"file\" name=\"file1\" id=\"file\" class=\"inputfile\">
        <label for=\"file\">Browse</label>
    </div>    

    <div class=\"upload-wrap\">
        <input placeholder=\"Choose a file..\" class=\"file-name\" type=\"text\">
        <input type=\"file\" name=\"file2\" id=\"file\" class=\"inputfile\">
        <label for=\"file\">Browse</label>
    </div>

    <div class=\"upload-wrap\">
        <input placeholder=\"Choose a file..\"  class=\"file-name\" type=\"text\">
        <input type=\"file\" name=\"file3\" id=\"file\" class=\"inputfile\">
        <label for=\"file\">Browse</label>
    </div>    

   <button class=\"manage-btn upload-btn\" type=\"submit\">Upload</button>

</form>

<div class=\"upload-alert\"></div>
```

JQuery & AJAX:

```
    $(document).on('submit','.upload-inputs', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
               url : "upload.php",
               method: "POST",
               data : new FormData(this),
               processData: false,
               contentType: false,
               success:function(mesg)
               {
                    $(".upload-alert").html(mesg);
               }

            });
        });
```

Not using multiple file selection because after checking in mobile browser (Chrome) I found that it doesn't allow multiple files selection in phone. So using different single input fields.

'upload.php' Code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  // Having this same code for 'file2' & file3 below (Just changing the variable names to file2 & file3)
  if(!empty($_FILES['file1']))
  {
    $file1 = $_FILES['file1'];

    $file1_name = $file1['name'];
    $file1_tmp = $file1['tmp_name'];
    $file1_error = $file1['error'];

    $file1_size = $file1['size'];
    $file1_size = $file1_size / 1024;
    $file1_size = number_format($file1_size, 0);

    $file1_ext = explode('.', $file1_name);
    $file1_ext = strtolower(end($file1_ext));
    $allowed = array('jpg');

        if (in_array($file1_ext, $allowed))
        {
            if($file1_error === 0)
            {
                if($file1_size <= 2048)
                {
                    $file1_name_new = uniqid(rand()) . ".$file1_ext"; 
                    $file1_destination = 'profile_image/'.$file1_name_new;

                    // Output if successfully moved. 

                    if (move_uploaded_file($file1_tmp, $file1_destination))
                    { 
                        echo " <div class=\"files-bar1\">
                        <button class=\"manage-btn delete-image\">Delete</button>        
                       <img class=\"image-thumb\" src=\"profile_image/$file1_name_new\">
                        <label class=\"image-name\">$file1_name_new</label><br>
                        <p class=\"image-size\">$file1_size KB</p><br>
                        <p class=\"percentage\">_% Completed</p><br/>
                    <progress class=\"upload-progress\" min=\"0\" max=\"100\"></progress>
                        <label class=\"stop-uploading\">&#10006;</label>
                    </div>";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        echo "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    echo "Image Size Must Be Under 2 MB.";
                }
            }

            else
            {
                echo "Caught Error.";
            }
    }

    else
    {
        echo "Only JPG/JPEG format is allowed.";
    }
}

    else
    {
      echo "file1 Undefined.";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set proper markup for form.

- Why do you use slashes(/) remove all slashes
- same id should not be provide multiple times in same page
- if you want to upload multiple files then you can user `multiple` instead of creating more inputs

So your markup should be

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload-inputs">

    <div class="upload-wrap">
        <input placeholder="Choose a file.." class="file-name" type="text">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" multiple max="3">
        <label for="file">Browse</label>
    </div>    

    <input name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" type="submit">

</form>
```

For script side
add file data to your before using ajax
So script should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = new FormData();
        jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function (i, file) {
            data.append('file' + i, file);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data); // To see output in console
            }
        });

    });
});
```

**If you want to limit your file upload to only 3 then you can put limits too.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
        if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 3) {
            alert("You can only upload a maximum of 3 files");
            return false;
        } else {
            var data = new FormData();
            jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function (i, file) {
                data.append('file' + i, file);
            });

            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

In `upload.php` you can receive out from `file0, file1, file2...` like this.

```
Array
(
    [file0] => Array
        (
            [name] => step1.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => D:\wamp\tmp\phpE8A7.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 56187
        )

    [file1] => Array
        (
            [name] => step2.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => D:\wamp\tmp\phpE8A8.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 56910
        )

    [file2] => Array
        (
            [name] => step3.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => D:\wamp\tmp\phpE8A9.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 57051
        )

    [file3] => Array
        (
            [name] => taxi_service-1.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => D:\wamp\tmp\phpE8BA.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 7741
        )

)
```

If any query, ask in comment.

Comment: Okay so, the ajax code you provided was not working for me.. I don't know how you managed to get the output but for me when I was uploading the images I was getting message "Undefined file1" which I've set to receive when my if condition returns false.

But one thing that tapped me which you told that I can't use same id for all the fields. So I used my working ajax code, changed IDs and it worked.

Also, the reason I'm using slashes in HTML because I'm outputting HTML form from a php file with ". And I wanted to stick with Multiple single input fields. 
Anyway, now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This problem got solved.** Only one file was getting uploaded by php due to the use of same IDs in 'label' and 'input' tags. No changes were required in Ajax Code.

Simply just IDs of each 'label' and 'input' tags is required to be changed.

Right Format:

```
<form action=\"upload.php\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" class=\"upload-inputs\">

        <div class=\"upload-wrap\">
            <input placeholder=\"Choose a file..\" class=\"file-name\" type=\"text\">
            <input type=\"file\" name=\"file1\" id=\"file1\" class=\"inputfile\">
            <label for=\"file1\">Browse</label><br>

            <input placeholder=\"Choose a file..\" class=\"file-name\" type=\"text\">
            <input type=\"file\" name=\"file2\" id=\"file2\" class=\"inputfile\">
            <label for=\"file2\">Browse</label><br>

            <input placeholder=\"Choose a file..\" class=\"file-name\" type=\"text\">
            <input type=\"file\" name=\"file3\" id=\"file3\" class=\"inputfile\">
            <label for=\"file3\">Browse</label><br>
       </div>

</form>
```